# Construct a Gamepad in js

Tags: javascript, gamepad

So I was trying to simulate a controller in JavaScript but couldn't find a way to construct a `new Gamepad()` and could not figure out how to work this out from the [docs](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#constructing-a-gamepad) could anybody help.

This is what my current code looks like:

```
function simulateControllerInput(key) {
    const mapping = keyMappings[key];
    if (mapping) {
        const simulatedGamepad = new Gamepad(); // <-- This is where I want to construct the Gamepad
        simulatedGamepad.axes = mapping.axes;
        const buttonEvent = new GamepadEvent("gamepadbuttondown", {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            gamepad: simulatedGamepad,
        });
        document.dispatchEvent(buttonEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens? What browser/version?

Comment: I would consult the mozilla docs as they are typically more up to date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API

Comment: @DaveNewton I receive this error "Illegal constructor at line 11" which is the line where "const simulatedGamepad = new Gamepad()" and my browser is Edge version 119.0.2151.93 I have also tried this code on Chrome version 119.0.6045.200

Comment: @DerekPollard I have checked the Mozilla docs for the Gamepad API, but there they never construct a new gamepad which is what I need which is possible as there is a section in the docs on how to construct a Gamepad https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#constructing-a-gamepad

Comment: From what I gather, those docs outline how the browsers are to implement the game pad. You get passed a gamepad instance from the browser, you don't initialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible because the Gamepad API specification doesn't define a constructor for `interface Gamepad`:

https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#gamepad-interface

Exposing an interface for creating simulated gamepads seems useful. If you want to pursue this please file a spec issue and we can continue the conversation there.

https://github.com/w3c/gamepad/issues

---

I think in your app it's not necessary to create a real `Gamepad` object. Just create a `new Object()` and set `axes`, `buttons`, and any other attributes your app expects.